# How to have different subdirectories for a website on Apache2?

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost, subdirectory

I have an Apache2 server that is configured to provide a website which is located in different folders as follows:

- `/var/www/main` contains the homepage file `index.html`
- `/var/www/sub` contains another file `sub.html`

While my website's homepage is accessible the sub-part is not:

- `www.mysite.com` (== `www.mysite.com/index.html`) works
- `ẁww.mysite.com/sub` does **not** work
- `ẁww.mysite.com/sub.html` does **not** work
- `ẁww.mysite.com/sub/sub.html` does **not** work

The error messages are always `requested URL ... was not found on this server`

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
    <Directory /var/www/sub>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    <Directory /var/www/main>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: this should go to serverfault, not stackoverflow

Comment: The problem with serverfault is the small number of users. It is quite hard to get an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need summat like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main
    Alias  /sub /var/www/sub
    <Directory /var/www/main>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/sub>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then `http://mysite.com/sub/sub.html` will be the sub file. `http://mysite.com/index.html` or `http://mysite.com` should also work.

If a sub-directory is not required you need to look into `ReWrite`

Comment: Ok I now use your conguration with the additional line `DirectoryIndex sub.html`. 
Now `mysite.com/sub/` will automatically show sub.html whereas `mysite.com/sub` is converted to `mysite.comsub`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Bastian - It does a search to find a file. Try it without `DocumentRoot`. If that does not work I will look up my notes.

Comment: Removing `DocumentRoot` does not change the behaviour :-(.

Comment: @Bastian - I just tried if. I think that you need the trailing `/` on both `<directory ...>` (i.e `<Directory /var/www/sub/>` and the alias i.e. `Alias  /sub /var/www/sub/`